# Unknown resource type: 'auth::file_array' trying to use Puppet's Defined Resource Type

Tags: puppet, manifest

I am creating authentication module which basically copies files like passwd, shadow and group etc from puppet server to agent on specified location

below is my manifest file init.pp

```
class auth (
  $groups        = $auth::params::groups,
  $users         = $auth::params::users,
  $default_shell = $auth::params::default_shell,
) inherits auth::params {
  include stdlib
  notify { 'Hello World': }
  # defined type for arrays of files with a common root directory and permissions
  define auth::file_array(
    $root_dir,
    $owner = 'root',
    $group = 'root',
    $mode  = '0644',
  ) {
    # validations
    if ($root_dir == undef) {
      fail("auth::file_array ${name} root_dir is undefined")
    }

    # push file, puppet:/// forces pull from Puppet server being used
    file { $name:
      ensure => file,
      owner  => $owner,
      group  => $group,
      path   => "/${root_dir}/${name}",
      source => "puppet:///modules/auth/${root_dir}/${name}",
      mode   => $mode,
    }
  }

  # 0644 files
  auth::file_array { ['krb5.conf', 'nsswitch.conf', 'group', 'pam_smb.conf', 'pam.d/gdm-password', 'pam.d/kdm', 'pam.d/login', 'pam.d/sshd', 'pam.d/su', 'pam.d/system-auth', 'pam.d/system-auth-ac', 'passwd', 'sysconfig/authconfig']:
    root_dir => 'etc',
  }

  # 0600 files
  auth::file_array { ['shadow', 'gshadow']:
    root_dir => 'etc',
    mode     => '0000',
  }

  # defined type for dynamic management of /etc/group
  define auth::dynamic_group() {
    $group = $name
    $gid   = $auth::groups[$group]['gid']
    $users = $auth::groups[$group]['users']

    # create groups
    group { $group:
      ensure  => present,
      gid     => $gid,
      require => File['group', 'gshadow'],
    }

    # purge group before adding members
    augeas { "purge_${group}":
      context => "/files/etc/group/${group}",
      changes => [
        'rm user',
      ],
      require => Group[$group],
    }

    # force unique resource titles (same user may be in multiple groups)
    $group_users = prefix($users, "${group}_")

    # add all members
    dynamic_group::member { $group_users:
      group   => $group,
      require => Augeas["purge_${group}"],
    }
  }

  # defined type for lower-level work supporting dynamic management of /etc/group
  define auth::dynamic_group::member($group) {
    # validations
    if( $group == undef ) {
      fail("auth::dynamic_group::member $name group is undefined")
    }

    # strip group name to get user
    $user = regsubst($name, "^${group}_", '')

    # add user to group
    augeas { "${group}_${user}":
      context => "/files/etc/group/${group}",
      changes => [
        "ins user after *[self::gid or self::user][last()]",
        "set user[last()] ${user}",
      ],
    }
  }

  # get group names from hash parameter
  $group_names = keys($auth::groups)
  # create groups, can't use create_resources here
  auth::dynamic_group { $group_names:
    before => Exec['fix_gshadow'],
  }
  # force sync w/ /etc/gshadow, in case users newgrp
  exec { 'fix_gshadow':
    command => 'grpconv',
    path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin'],
  }

  # defined type for hostname specific user overrides
  # this can force removal of accounts on specific machines, changing passwords, ...
  define auth::hostname_user_override(
    $pattern,
    $user,
    $groups,
    $ensure = 'present',
    $shell = $auth::default_shell,
    $password = '!!',
  ) {
    # validations
    if( $pattern == undef ) {
      fail("auth::user_override $name pattern undefined")
    }
    if( $user == undef ) {
      fail("auth::user_override $name user undefined")
    }
    if( $groups == undef ) {
      fail("auth::user_override $name groups undefined")
    }

    if( regexp_match_variable($::hostname, $pattern)) {
      user { $name:
        ensure   => $ensure,
        name     => $user,
        groups   => $groups,
        shell    => $shell,
        password => $password,
        require  => File['passwd', 'shadow'],
      }
    }
  }

  create_resources(auth::hostname_user_override, $user_overrides)
}
```

param.pp

```
class auth::params {
  $groups = {
    'owner'   => {
      'gid'   => '102',
      'users' => $::fqdn ? {
        default => $::machine_owner ? {
          undef   => [],
          ""      => [],
          default => [$::machine_owner],
        },
      },
    },
    'qpadm'    => {
      'gid'   => '1000',
      'users' => $::fqdn ? {
        default => $::machine_owner ? {
          undef   => [],
          ""      => [],
          default => [$::machine_owner],
        },
      },
    },
    'docker'    => {
      'gid'   => '2000',
      'users' => $::fqdn ? {
        default => $::machine_owner ? {
          undef   => [],
          ""      => [],
          default => [$::machine_owner],
        },
      },
    },
    'sasl'   => {
      'gid'   => '6235',
      'users' => $::fqdn ? {
        /pd-dcm-test-[12]\.eng\.qpass\.net/ => $::machine_owner ? {
          undef   => ['ganeshna', 'sukeshk'],
          ""      => ['ganeshna', 'sukeshk'],
          default => [$::machine_owner, 'ganeshna', 'sukeshk'],
        },
        default => $::machine_owner ? {
          undef   => [],
          ""      => [],
          default => [$::machine_owner],
        },
      },
    },
  }

  # $user_overrides is for hostname_user_override management
  $user_overrides = {
    'bpainter_remove_root_password' => {
      pattern  => 'bpainter',
      user     => 'root',
      groups   => 'root',
    },
  }

  # default shell for modifying/creating user accounts
  $default_shell = '/bin/bash'
}
```

I called this module in node.pp as
include auth
But when I run the puppet agent -t on agent node I am getting below error
`Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'auth::file_array' (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/auth/manifests/init.pp, line: 30, column: 2) on node testmachine.example.com`

puppet server version is 7.28.0

Note: Same code is running on puppet version 3.8.7